# Bootstrap 4 Carousel component Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement Carousel Bootstrap 4 to a personal project. I have basic understanding of HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap 4 and JS. I have look to several discussions and tutorials on how to use the carousel component, but cannot get the correct output in the browser. I use chrome and firefox and have the same problem in both browsers. I already check the paths of (link) and (script) , I even had to change the (img data-src="#") to (img src="#") so the images could load properly into the browser. The images are on top of each other and don't know how to correct this problem. I copy the code directly from the Bootstrap website. This is my first time in a community and my first question. Just feeling a bit of frustration with this component.

Thanks in advance!

[Image example of problem in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1reLh.png)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>Carousel-testing!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\bootstrap-theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\animate.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets\js\jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets\js\bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets\js\app.js"></script>
</head>

<nav>

</nav>

<section id="carousel">

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="assets\images\2736779-casino-roulette-in-water-and-fire-isolated-on-black-background.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="assets\images\DealerBust.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="assets\images\FH_Gaming_Main-new.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>

<body>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your HTML inside the `<body>` tag in order for it to render properly.

```
<body>
<nav>

</nav>

<section id="carousel">

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="assets\images\2736779-casino-roulette-in-water-and-fire-isolated-on-black-background.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="assets\images\DealerBust.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="assets\images\FH_Gaming_Main-new.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, I put the html inside the body tag. Still doesn't work the carousel component.

Comment: Is there an error that shows up in the console? Try moving the Bootstrap and app JS script tags to the bottom of the body.

Comment: Yes litel, the console told me there was an error in line 441 inside bootstrap.js A friend told me to download all the bootstrap files and start from scratch. Now everything is working propertly, don't know what caused the error but that's seems to do the trick. Thanks for the promp reply!

Answer (score 0):

Change the class "carousel-item" to "item".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

<title>Carousel-testing!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\bootstrap-theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\app.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\animate.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets\js\jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets\js\bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets\js\app.js"></script>
</head>

<nav>

</nav>

<section id="carousel">

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="assets\images\2736779-casino-roulette-in-water-and-fire-isolated-on-black-background.jpg" alt="First slide">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="assets\images\DealerBust.jpg" alt="Second slide">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="assets\images\FH_Gaming_Main-new.jpg" alt="Third slide">
  </div>
</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: On Bootstrap 4, the `item` class has been changed to `carousel-item`. http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/

Comment: That's true Rajat. I had to download bootstrap again, start from scratch and now its working good. Don't know what was the error, but now its fix. Thanks for the promp reply!